# TestNg.run resulting null pointer exception when the suite is made programmatically

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I need to generate the test suites programmatically based on the parameters of the test.

This is the main function:

```
public class DataValidator {
public static void main (String args[]) {
    TestState testState = new TestState();

    //Create an instance on TestNG
    TestNG testNg = new TestNG();

    List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();

    TestRunner testRunner = new TestRunner(testState);
    XmlSuite testSuite = testRunner.generateSuite();

    suites.add(testSuite);
    testNg.setXmlSuites(suites);
    testNg.run();
}   
}
```

This is the test runner that generates the test suites

```
public class TestRunner {
   private TestState testState;

public TestRunner(TestState testState) {
    this.testState = testState;
}


public XmlSuite generateSuite( ) {
    XmlSuite testSuite = new XmlSuite();
    XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest();
    xmlTest.setName("TestState");    

    List<XmlClass> xmlClasses = new ArrayList<XmlClass>();

    xmlClasses.add(new XmlClass(JobCreated.class.getName()));
    xmlTest.setXmlClasses(xmlClasses);
    testSuite.addTest(xmlTest);
    return testSuite;
}
```

This is the jobcreated class

```
public class JobCreated {

@Test
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("passed test 1");
}
}
```

When I run the test as java application, I get the following NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.testng.xml.XmlTest.getVerbose(XmlTest.java:249)
at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:212)
at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:167)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:663)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:198)
at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)
at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at data_validator_testng.DataValidator.main(DataValidator.java:39)
```

I am unable to understand what is causing this error.

Answer (score 4):

since there's no proper link among XmlTest and m_suite falls null

```
/**
* @return Returns the verbose.
*/
public int getVerbose() {
  Integer result = m_verbose;
  if (null == result || XmlSuite.DEFAULT_VERBOSE.equals(m_verbose)) {
    result = m_suite.getVerbose(); 
}
```

It was rectified by adding `testSuite` to the constructor of XmlTest

```
XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(testSuite);
```

This [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/riggFkRaLPY) was helpful in finding the solution